# std::bind compiler error gcc

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, gcc

In one of my recent projects, I did the development work on Ubuntu (cmake+gcc 4.8.4). The code builds fine. However, when I attempt to build the same code in cygwin (cmake + gcc 5.3), I get a compiler error for std::bind. This goes away on doing a `#include <functional>`. However, this worries me a little bit. I expect my code to work fine on identical or very similar compilers.

I have just shipped out a piece of code which will be used on a CentOS. I just assumed that because my code builds fine with Ubuntu, other linux distributions with a similar compiler should not be a problem. However, I am no longer sure if my code will build fine on CentOS.

My question is this. Can I assume that if my code builds fine with a particular version of gcc on my Ubuntu machine, it will also build fine on other linux distributions with the same or higher version of gcc? Or am I being overly optimistic and should rely more testing? Or this has something to do with std::bind itself?

Comment: The [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) function is declared in the `<functional>` standard header file. Just because you are lucky enough that some other header file just happens to include it doesn't mean anything. If you want to use `std::bind` you should explicitly include `<functional>`.

Comment: Didn't you answer your own question in the question? I'm confused.

Answer (score 3):

There is no guarantee that all gcc compiler versions behave the same. In particular w.r.t. C++ 11 features there were some incompatible changes between the compiler versions. gcc 4.8 had still only experimental C++ 11 support. The standard says that std::bind comes with `<functional>`, so gcc 5.3 correctly demands you to include it:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind

It is possible that older versions of gcc either included `<functional>` in some other include you have, or that bind was provided in another include.

It is always a good idea to test software on different compiler versions and even with a completely different compiler (like clang). Otherwise you might use extensions or small deviations from the C++ standard without knowing it and thus be tied to that particular compiler version.

Answer (score 2):

If you forgot to include `<functional>` before using `std::bind`, your code is not standard-compliant, and has no guarantee to work anywhere. That it worked on your particular toolchain is unfortunate luck.

Comment: But how could it ever work without including `<functional>`?

Comment: @cplusplusrat another header you included uses `<functional>` internally, or at least the part of it that defines `std::bind`.

Answer (score 2):

> My question is this. Can I assume that if my code builds fine with a particular version of gcc on my Ubuntu machine, it will also build fine on other linux distributions with the same or higher version of gcc?

No you cannot.  Your version may have had a bug that allows a piece of non conforming code to compile and the later version could have that fixed which would lead to a compiler error for that offending code.

In fact this is basically what happened to you.  It is not really a bug per se but you used a function from a standard header and you never included that header.  `std::bind` lives in `<functional>`.  The fact that it compiled without the inclusion of `<functional>` is non standard behavior.  When you moved to a compiler that did not include `<functional>` in one of the header you do include it broke the compilation.

> Or am I being overly optimistic and should rely more testing?

Yes you should test the code on multiple compilers and systems if you are trying to release truly portable code.  Your best defense is to write strictly 100% standard conforming code.

> Or this has something to do with std::bind itself?

This has nothing to do with `std::bind` but with how conforming you make you code.  Not including `<functional>` when it is required makes you code non conforming.

Comment: Yep, all reasonable suggestions and time permitting, I would have done a much stricter code review. Sigh.... such is life. Live and learn...

Comment: @cplusplusrat Yep. It is generally from our failures that we learn the most.

Comment: Guess, a related question for me is this. How does one ever know if a code strictly follows C++ 11 standard. Enforcing C++ 11 standard via code reviews is not a feasible solution for any non-trivial project. So my natural answer to this is testing. But how many different compilers and versions are there? Guess what I am asking is, how much testing would you do, if reading the entire code base is not an option, to ensure that your code rigidly follows C++11 standard?

Comment: To give some more context, gcc 5.3 will happily compile `std::bind` with `<memory>` without needing the said `<functional>`